# decltype, universal references and forward for containers in C++

Tags: c++, templates, pass-by-reference, decltype, forwarding-reference

I am reading about `decltype` and rvalue references in effective modern C++ by Scott Meyers book. I have following code

```
template <typename container, typename index>
decltype(auto) authAndAccess(container&& c, index i)  {
    std::cout << "auth and Access c type: " << typeid(c[i]).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "auth and Access c type expecting reference: " << typeid(std::forward<container>(c)[i]).name() << std::endl;
    return std::forward<container>(c)[i];
}

deque<int> makeStringDeque() {
    deque<int> dqContainer = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    return dqContainer;
}
```

now in main function I have following

```
deque<int> dqContainer = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
std::cout << "Value returned by container: " << authAndAccess(dqContainer, 4) << std::endl;
authAndAccess(deque<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 4) = 10;
std::cout << "Value returned by container and 5th element after copying: " << dqContainer[4] << endl;
```

My question is `authAndAccess` function takes rvalue argument so container is temporary and return is object is temporary reference element. But why output is shown as `int` for `typeid` of forwared for which I am expecting `int &`. I do understand name function of typeid is not accurate, but why it is not crashing as we are returning temporary element reference.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is `authAndAccess` function takes rvalue argument so container is temporary and return is object is temporary reference element.

`authAndAccess` takes what Scott called a Universal Reference, which is now called a forwarding reference, so it can accept lvalue and rvalue arguments.  When you pass it a lvalue, you get a lvalue reference and when you pass it an rvalue you get a rvalue reference.  `std::forward<container>` does the same thing.  If `container` is a lvalue, you get a lvalue and for rvalues you get a rvalue.

That means `authAndAccess(dqContainer, 4)` is fine since you are returning a reference to an object in `dqContainer` which still exists.  In `authAndAccess(makeStringDeque(), 4)` you would think you have undefined behavior since `makeStringDeque()` is a temporary and you are returning a reference to it but since you don't keep it, there is no UB since the reference will be valid until the end of the full expression.

---

> But why output is shown as `int` for `typeid` of forwared for which I am expecting `int &`.

`typeid` won't tell you if you have a reference.  You can see that in this minimal example

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a = 5;
    int & b = a;
    std::cout << typeid(b).name();
}
```

which outputs `i`.  If you wan to get the type you can use a declared but not defined class template and give the type to it and you'll get an error message telling you what the actual type is.  If we change the above code to

```
template<typename T>
struct type;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int a = 5;
    int & b = a;
    type<decltype(b)>{};
}
```

we will get an error like

```
main.cpp:14:5: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'type<int &>'
    type<decltype(b)>{};
```

and as you can see it deduces the type as `int &`.  If we do that in your code it also gives `int &` since that is the return type of `c[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. By the way can you please elaborate following statement. "you are returning a reference to it but since you don't keep it, there is no UB since the reference will be valid until the end of the full expression.". What is UB here means? Thanks

Comment: @venkysmarty UB means Undefined behavior.  There are many cases in C++ where the standard lets the code compile, but doesn't define what should happen.  When you do something that has no defined behavior then you have undefined behavior.  Had you kept a reference to the return of `authAndAccess(makeStringDeque(), 4)` and the  used it you would be accessing a variable that no longer exists and the standard has no mandate for what should happen so we say it has UB.

Comment: @ NathanOliver. Thanks, now I able to get concept.